# Rspec 3.1.0 - why is the #to method unavailable for 'True'?

Tags: rspec

Why is only the (deprecated) `#should` statement working for me?
The commented-out `#expect` statements fail although they follow the example in the curriculum exactly.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Vote do

  describe "validations" do

    describe 'value validation' do
      it "only allows -1 or 1 as values" do

        vgood1 = Vote.create :value => 1
        vgood2 = Vote.create :value => -1
        vbad1 = Vote.create :value => 0
        vbad2 = Vote.create :value => 2
        vbad3 = Vote.create
        expect (vgood1.valid?).should == true#eq(true)
        # expect (vgood2.valid?).to eq(true)
        # expect (vbad1.valid?).to eq(false)
        # expect (vbad2.valid?).to eq(false)
        # expect (vbad3.valid?).to eq(false)

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the example in the curriculum

```
Failures:

  1) Vote validations value validation only allows -1 or 1 as values
     Failure/Error: expect(bad_v.valid?).to eq(false)

       expected: false
            got: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a whitespace error.

Because of implied parentheses, Ruby reads this:

```
expect (vgood2.valid?).to eq(true)
```

as this:

```
expect((vgood2.valid?).to eq(true))
```

In this latter case, `(vgood2.valid?)` is the object that doesn't have a `to` method defined on it.